# Server.MapPath issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, server.mappath

So I am reading a book about asp.net security. and one of the sections there was : 
how to prevent directory traversal filename ( hacked filenames).

so the line of code was :

`string fullPath = Server.MapPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(@"d:\inetpub\inbound\",filename));`

but then I noticed the  result of the combine which will be :

```
d:\inetpub\inbound\myfile.txt
```

But I remember that the parameter type should be **virtual** path  and not filesystem path !

[image]

`d:\inetpub\inbound\myfile.txt` is not a virtual path!

what am I missing ?

[image]

p.s. this is the book : (wrox)

[image]

Comment: Passing any kind of filesystem path is surely wrong. I would not trust that book ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code sample is wrong.

The role of `Server.MapPath` is indeed to transform a virtual path into a physical one. If you already have a physical path, there'a no need for `Server.MapPath`.

The code will probably throw an Exception with the message:

> 'd:\inetpub\inbound\myfile.txt' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `Server.MapPath` to convert a *virtual* path (i.e., a path inside your website) to a *physical* path (such as `D:\InetPub\`...).

So you can do this:

```
var physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Incoming/Receivedfile.txt");
```

and then you can use `physicalPath` to actually access the file.

BTW the tilde in the filename above represents the root of the website the code is running under.

Comment: how this is actually answer my question ? I know i can use tilde or [.] and then see the filesystempath. Im talking about different scenario...:-)

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood your question then... What is your question?

Comment: Server.mappath should get a virtual path. and d:\adad.asdsd is not a virtual path.

Comment: No, Roy is right. You're using Server.MapPath incorrectly. You don't need Server.MapPath as you already have the physical path of the file.

Comment: @Simon I already know it. I also noticed it in the book. thats why i'm asking